# Is the getnewaddress command available before synchronization is completed?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, synchronization

Can I expect the `getnewaddress` command to work before my `bitcoind` has finished synchronizing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `getnewaddress` works independent of the downloading and indexing of your blockchain database.

The command will generate a new private key in your wallet.dat file. This file is independent of the state of your blockchain files.

Your new address is derived from the freshly generated private key.

Your client will need to be synced to see incoming transactions (deposits) on your address reflected in your balance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Here's a screenshot for `getnewaddress` on the Bitcoin Core's debug console while the wallet is not fully synced:

[image]